# .net MAUI appicon strange scaling on Android

Tags: android, .net-maui

When I assign a png as appicon to a MAUI app, I have an issue of odd scaling, which means that the given icon image does load, but it is cutting away a large section of the outer part of the image.
I tried this with multiple images, and this was never an issue using Xamarin and Android.
I did try setting the BaseSize property to whatever size the image has, as well as various others to test, and it made no visible difference. I did also try setting the ForegroundScaling option, which did make a difference, but I was unable to ever tweak it to be correct, and I assume it should not be required in the first place.

Below is an image, I am assigning, and the result being shown on an Android device (I did not test on other platforms). It seems that about 80% of the image is kept.

I would expect it to cut mostly the corners when keeping whatever is inside the inscribed circle in this rectangular image, but it apparently does this with a circle that has a diameter of some 80% of the width and height of the image.

[image: The image I am assigning as app icon]
[image: What I see on an Android device]

Comment: Add to question all relevant code.

Comment: There is no relevant code, as this is just using the initial proto project entry of   <MauiIcon Include=".... It just clips a given png as demonstrated

Comment: You can try to use Vector graphics.

Comment: I would be very interested in knowing if this is a general issue. I also did try using a svg which had the same issue, so either I am doing something wrong (though I am literally just modifying the default maui apps icon here), or something else is funky

Comment: If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?  Thanks for your support and feedback for maui.

Comment: also bothered with this. i have created a repository @JessieZhang-MSFT : https://github.com/yueyinqiu/stackoverflow73414054.git

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/990590/maui-appicon-strange-scaling-on-android.html

Comment: Did anybody find a reasonable solution to this issue, I'm having it Mar 28, 2023

Answer (score 1):

You should use SVG better and add **ForegroundScale="0.65"**(in .csproj), something like:

```
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" **ForegroundScale="0.65"** Color="#000000" />
```